# Android Studio 4.0, can't find LLDB in SDK-manager?

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb

I know there are similar questions but most of them are either incomplete or don't really answer the question at all.

So I just installed Android Studio 4.0 and I need to install LLDB in the SDK Tools tab. However LLDB doesn't show in the list so I can't even select it to download/install:

[image: SDK Tools without LLDB in list]

I'm following a guide that does a fresh install of Android Studio where LLDB shows in the list from the start so I'm not really sure what I have to do to be able to install it?

I've searched around a bit both here and on Google and most answers talk about proxy settings but have incomplete or missing comments. There are no error messages in the SDK Update Sites tab either.

To be clear this is without any open projects since I just installed it and I'm trying to set everything up as according to the guide which is pretty recent from this year. Also I'm on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4.

I'm sure it's going to turn out to be an easy fix and that I'm just being silly but I really could use some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk:

LLDB: the debugger Android Studio uses to debug native code. By default, LLDB will be installed alongside Android Studio.

Comment: Yeah but if you scroll down on the page you linked there's an image showing LLDB being installed. That doesn't show for me, it just isn't in the list.